# token sell and buy prices

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

Hi for a while now i have been testing ethereum capabilities and there is something i wanted to test and i cant figure how to do. When creating a contract of a custom token (using the code given in the ethereum official site) there is a sell price to set and a buy price for a token, in what way can i use this to give a token sell price of another token?

What I mean is, is there a way to give token A price in token B? essentialy making it possible to a user who have Token B to buy token A? and could a contract hold more than 1 kind of a token? like a contract that holds both token A and B? and maybe even more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Token contract](https://www.ethereum.org/token) has a function that allows the token owner to approve an address for a certain amount. This other address will be able to send up to this amount of the approver's tokens:

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) {}
```

So let's say you have 2 people Alice and Bob. Alice has 3 TokenA and Bob has 4 TokenB. They agree to exchange them. You create the re-usable `Trade` contract to make that happen.

```
contract Trade {
    function exchange(address alice, 
                    address tokenA,
                    uint qtyTokenA,
                    address bob,
                    address tokenB,
                    uint qtyTokenB) 
        returns (bool success) {
        success = Token(tokenA).transferFrom(alice, bob, qtyTokenA)
            && Token(tokenB).transferFrom(bob, alice, qtyTokenB);
        if (!success) throw;
    }
}
```

In TokenA, Alice approves the trade contract for `3`. In TokenB, Bob approves the trade contract for `4`. Then someone calls the `exchange` function with the proper values.

I understand that, as it stands, there is a security risk whereby Carol calls the method before others, to steal from Alice. IRL, you would have Alice and Bob to both approve the `exchange` function call.

Comment: so in order to do that i must have another contract in place? it cannot be done in a token contract right? like have 10 tokens and 1 main token which all of the others have a price according to? (is this example possible ?alice has token A bob has token B and my system runs token P ---> token A and B both have exchange function for token P in them and that exchange ratio would be defined by me, now when they trade they can get the P tokens and exchange then replace them with A or B? i know its a bit hard to understand me here ^^) thanks btw!

Comment: It is better to keep TokenA and TokenB "simple", and work with other systems. If you introduce TokenP that is the "currency of exchange", then you need to modify `function exchange` to take more parameters. I suppose `tokenP` and `alicePay` and `bobPay`. Or some other combination.

Comment: ye but given I might need someday to exchange between many different tokens wouldnt it be smarter to have them all point to P somehow?

Comment: You can indeed include this function within your TokenP.